# Enable Dropdownlist when a condition is true using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC c# project. I am new to JQuery and would love it if you guys could lend some ideas as to what went wrong here..

I have two drop down lists:

```
            @Html.DropDownList("year", new SelectList(SomeModel.SomeHelper.SomeMethod()), "All", new {@class = "dropDown"})

            @Html.DropDownList("month", new SelectList(new[]
            {
                new {ID = "1", Name = "January"},
                new {ID = "2", Name = "February"},


            }, "ID", "Name"),"All", new {@class = "dropDown", @disabled = "disabled"})
```

Note: most months removed on purpose

Year list will always be enabled. But month list is only to be enabled if a value is selected from year list. Therefore i wrote this JQuery which works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var yearDropdown = $("#year");
    var monthDropdown = $("#month");

   yearDropdown.on('change', function (sender, arg) {
        var newVal = $(this).val();
        monthDropdown.removeAttr('disabled', newVal !== 0);
    }); 

});
```

However, now.. when i do not want year to be selected (i go back to selecting 'all' in year list ), month list is still enabled.

***EDIT:*** Year list contains values like "2010", "2011" .. etc. When "all" is selected for year list i want month list disabled. When an year is selected, i want month list enabled.

Therefore i wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var monthDropdown = $("#month");
        var yearDropdown = $("#year");

        yearDropdown.on('change', function (sender, arg) {
            if ($(yearDropdown) == "All") {
                $("#monthDropdown").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Which did not work.. (which means nothing at all happened) and i am not sure if that's the right way to do it even. So as of right now: Only selection of year from year list enables the month list. Nothing more..

Any guidance? :)

***UPDATE:***

With guidance of all those who commented, i managed to write a jquery that finally worked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var yearDropdown = $("#year");
        var monthDropdown = $("#month");

        yearDropdown.on('change', function() {
            var newVal = $("#year").val();
            if (newVal === "") {
                monthDropdown.prop('disabled', !this.selectedIndex);
            }
            else {
                monthDropdown.prop('enabled', !this.selectedIndex);
            }
        });

    });
```

Also now i have a better understanding of jquery :) Though im marking one answer as answer, the comments really counted!

Comment: `All` is option text or value? If value, what is purpose of `0`? FYI, value isn't a number but a string and removeAttr() jq method doesn't accept a boolean parameter and a jq object is always truly in js. That's make many things wrong in your code. Posting relevant HTML markup in your question itself would make your issue resolved in seconds...

Comment: "all" is the default value i set in each of the list</br>

<code>@Html.DropDownList("year", new SelectList(SomeModel.SomeHelper.SomeMethod()), "All", new {@class = "dropDown"})</code>

I did not set a value for it.. as i am still not fully sure of how it works. But i am able to retrieve values from this list in controller, when all is selected i use less than 0 to identify it.</br>

Also .. what did you mean by relevant HTML markup?

Comment: Jquery is client side language. It is used on browser. You have posted server side code, you should instead post the relevant slect elements HTML markup as it is rendered by the browser. Now it is easy to understand what is HTML rendering from your server side code but as i'm not an ASP guy, this ask me to much brain storming... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff wouldnt that be the same as this jquery?

Comment: I don't understand your queston. Anyway, this would work: `yearDropdown.on('change', function () {
        monthDropdown.prop('disabled', !this.selectedIndex);
    });`

Comment: That's working!!!! :D Care to explain how !this.selectedIndex part works as an answer? :)

Comment: Inspect the html your generating! There is no option with `value="0"` or `value=All"` There are however ones with `value=""` - you need to check `if ($(this).val() {` - i.e check for `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you mean that "all" there will have  a null value?

Comment: Look at the html. Your first option in each `<select>` is `<option value>All<option>`. That is a result of the 3rd parameter of the `DropDownListFor()` method which renders an optionLabel with a `null` value so it can be used in conjunction with the `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke .. oh! That clears up a lot of doubt i had! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$(yearDropdown)` you get the jQuery element (a wrapper on DOM element).

Use `$(yearDropdown).val()` to get the actual value!

Comment: Tried that with if ($(yearDropdown).val == "All")  and if ($(yearDropdown).val < 0) .. no change

Comment: Marked as answer because you had the = $("#year").val(); part right all along :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `.prop()`

```
monthDropdown.prop('disabled', newVal != 0);
```

---

and you have to check for the value:

```
yearDropdown.on('change', function (sender, arg) {
    if (yearDropdown.val() == "All") { // use `.val()` to check the value
        $("#monthDropdown").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

or

```
yearDropdown.on('change', function (sender, arg) {
    $("#monthDropdown").prop("disabled", this.value == "All");
});
```

Comment: _when i do not want year to be selected (i go back to selecting 'all' in year list ), month list is still enabled._ this is a bit confusing.

Comment: I guess it should be `newVal !== "0"` or `newVal != 0`

Comment: @A.Wolff i guess the issue is the second one because he/she says that one is working and in the second one instead of checking the value, checked the jqueyr object.

Comment: @Jai Both OP code are wrong, value is always a string, not a number

Comment: @A.Wolff agreed absolutely.

Comment: @A.Wolff undestood about the string part. I tried if ($(yearDropdown) == "All")  after if ($(yearDropdown) < 0 ) did not work...

Comment: @Tsar okay clarify one thing, did you bound two change events on single element?

Comment: @Jai nop.. how do i do that?